# What is this file compression technique

Tags: compression

How to extract this file ??

[File](https://www.mediafire.com/file/551tqu6senqad67/map_main/file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So file is the program function library under Linux, that is, the compiled code and data that can be used by other programs.

1. So files follow DLL file is similar.
2. Generally speaking, so files are often referred to as dynamic link libraries, which are compiled by C or C + +. Compared with Java, it is usually a class file (bytecode).
3. So files under Linux cannot be run directly. Generally speaking So files are called shared libraries.
4. So file usage

(1) Compilation of dynamic library. Here is a header file: so_ test. h. Three C file: Test_ a.c、test_ b.c、test_ c. C, we compile these files into a dynamic library: libtest so。
Command: $GCC test_ a.c test_ b.c test_ c.c -fPIC -shared -o libtest. So without this flag, external programs cannot connect. Equivalent to an executable file.

(2) Links to dynamic libraries
Here is a program source file test C and dynamic library libtest So link to generate the execution file test:
Command: $GCC test c -L. -ltest -o test
Command: $LDD test executes test. You can see how it calls functions in the dynamic library.